# what is "local block" in pg_stat_statements?

Tags: postgresql

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/pgstatstatements.html

```
local_blks_hit  bigint      Total number of local block cache hits by the statement
local_blks_read bigint      Total number of local blocks read by the statement
local_blks_dirtied  bigint      Total number of local blocks dirtied by the statement
local_blks_written  bigint      Total number of local blocks written by the statement
```

Doc says "local block" and where does it point to??

Answer (score 3):

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-explain.html:

> Shared blocks contain data from regular tables and indexes; local blocks contain data from temporary tables and indexes; while temp blocks contain short-term working data used in sorts, hashes, Materialize plan nodes, and similar cases.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, local_* fields refer to temporary tables and their indices.

By comparison, temp_* fields actually refer to temporary files (as in files used e.g. for external sorts due to memory constraints).

For context: I'm the author of [pganalyze](https://pganalyze.com/), a Postgres monitoring tool built on pg_stat_statements data amongst other statistics.